# И снова запятая перед тире

Tags: пунктуация

Этот вопрос тут поднимали уже много раз. Но меня интересует конкретно оборот: "...в-третьих(,) — для того, чтобы транспорт был более заметен на дороге, на воде или в воздухе". Сейчас не идет речь о том, нужно тут тире или нет, а именно о запятой в этом конкретном случае. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

А почему запятой не должно быть? Вводное слово выделяется запятой. Тире, которое вы ставите, видимо, в неполном предложении, ее не отменяет.